# Restore TensorFlow model on different machine

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained on TensorFlow model on a GPU cluster, saved the model using

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, config.model_file, global_step=global_step)
```

and now I am trying to restore the model with

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model-1000.meta')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(save_path))
```

for evaluation, on a different system. The issue is that `saver.restore`
yields the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/jonpdeaton/Developer/BraTS18-Project/segmentation/evaluate.py", line 205, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/jonpdeaton/Developer/BraTS18-Project/segmentation/evaluate.py", line 162, in main
    restore_and_evaluate(save_path, model_file, output_dir)
  File "/Users/jonpdeaton/Developer/BraTS18-Project/segmentation/evaluate.py", line 127, in restore_and_evaluate
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(save_path))
  File "/Users/jonpdeaton/anaconda3/envs/BraTS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1857, in latest_checkpoint
    if file_io.get_matching_files(v2_path) or file_io.get_matching_files(
  File "/Users/jonpdeaton/anaconda3/envs/BraTS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 337, in get_matching_files
    for single_filename in filename
  File "/Users/jonpdeaton/anaconda3/envs/BraTS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/jdeaton/dfs/unet; No such file or directory
```

It seems as though there are some paths that were stored in the model or `checkpoint` file form the system that it was trained on, that are no longer valid on the system that I am doing evaluation on. How do I restore a model (for evaluation) on a different machine after having copied the `model-X.meta`, `model-X.index` and `checkpoint` files?

Comment: use aboslute path to to meta file and save path, /home/jon/saved/model-1000.meta' and save_path=/home/jon/saved

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan I am.

Comment: probably not related to the model you restored, could you post the full error log,does the error point to the exact same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `Saver` object will write the absolute model checkpoint paths into the `checkpoint` file. So the path returned by `tf.train.latest_checkpoint(save_path)` is the absolute path on your old machine.

Temporary solution:

1. Pass the actual model file path directly to the `restore` method rather than the result of `tf.train.latest_checkpoint`.
2. Manually edit the `checkpoint` file, which is a simple text file.

Long term solution:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(save_relative_paths=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up the checkpoint file with your favorite text editor and simply change the absolute paths found therein to just filenames.